# Ajax call change browser url

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a problem with ajax call with custom route...I put this code in the index.js of my custom template for pieces page:

```
self.route('post', 'search-icons', function(req, res) {
    return async.series({
        list: function(callback){
            self.apos.docs.getManager('icon').find(req, {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "title": {
                            $regex : ".*"+req.body.search+".*"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "tags": {
                            $regex : ".*"+req.body.search+".*"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
                .toArray(function(err, icons) {

                    if (err) {
                        self.apos.utils.error(err);
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        callback(err);
                    }

                    res.send(self.render(req, 'indexAjax', { pieces: icons }));

                });
        }

    }, function(err){

    });
});
```

When I request this route with ajax the browser address(url) change...I'm not able to understand how I could avoid this behavior, because for me it's better if the url not changes.

thanks in advance
Roberto

Comment: That will be an issue in your browser side code, not your server side code. Share the browser side code.

Comment: If your code is associated with a form or a link and is not really firing at all or not cancelling the default behavior of the event through jQuery or by returning false, the url will change.

Comment: Yes the problem was in my browser side code...because I use apos.ui.ajaxGo to do ajax call and in the options I don't set push to false....now it's ok
thank you very much